# Ugly graphics after suspend. Is there a solution?

Tags: nvidia, gnome

So this is what i'm seeing on my Macbook Pro 5,3 running Ubuntu 11.10 with gnome-shell and nvidia graphics card after i have resumed from a suspend. The icons on the left hand side was also blurred with noise as you can see on the text, but that seemed to have fixed itself after some time, maybe it had something to do with me taking a screenshot, idk. Anyways, speculation aside, has anyone seen this kind of a behavior after a suspend command was given? And more importantly; any known fixes?

Thanks a bunch!

[LARGE VERSION NO1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZR7B.jpg)

[image: image showing uglyness]

[LARGE VERSION NO2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnqH9.jpg)

[image: image showing uglyness again]

Comment: What driver version are you using?

Comment: nvidia-current (280.13)

Answer (score 4):

Update your driver to 290.10.

Dont forget to remove the old driver first. You can downloaded it directly from the nVidia site or by adding the X Ubuntu PPA.

Comment: Nope, the issue came back after a few suspends.

Comment: Shame :( I'll have a look at it later on

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this bug can be related to yours..the problem is similar, because it affects the nvidia driver that you are using, that is nvidia-current 280.13-0ubuntu3..

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/854347

If it is related, click on "It affects me" so that it should be solved asap..

Answer (score 0):

You can install [nvidia-current-updates](http://packages.ubuntu.com/nvidia-current-updates) to get a newer version of the nVidia driver.

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates
```